# Route is not working when I access laravel application through localhost

Tags: laravel, routes

I have a laravel project and I can access this application through virtual server (tracking.com) locally. When I run through virtual server all the routes are working perfectly. But when I access the application through localhost (localhost/tracking/public) routes are not working except home page.

Home Route

```
Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@info')->middleware('auth');
```

Non-working routes

```
Route::resource('depot', 'DepotsController')->middleware('auth')
```

All routes are working well with virtual server. With virtual server both routes are working home page(tracking.com) and depots page (tracking.com/depot).

but with localhost only (localhost/tracking/public) is working and (localhost/depot) is not working.

Comment: point your virtual host to laravel project's `public` directory

Answer (score 0):

There are three solutions to this issue -

1) If you have Apache or Nginx installed, configure your vhost to point to /public/ directly

2) Use Laravel Homestead

3) Navigate to your project-folder/ within your terminal and run php artisan serve, you can now browse to http://localhost:8000 directly in your browser

Ref: If you are going with the first approach - [Click here](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/584/how-to-configure-a-virtual-host-for-a-laravel-project-in-xampp-for-windows)

Answer (score 0):

use `php artisan serve` and navigate to `127.0.0.1:8000` from they all the routes will work

Comment: Tried it.. I am getting "Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>.  But when I try 127.0.0.1:8000 it says site can't be reached.

Comment: yeah you need to generate a key for your application.

Comment: just run php artisan key:migrate and our app wll be working. feel free and enjoy.

Comment: I have generation the key using "php artisan key: generate" but the " php artisan key:migrate" is not working. It say command is not defined

Comment: its not php artisan key:migrate, its php artisan key:generate. Sorry for that

Comment: you need to do that for fresh installs

Comment: it sets an encription key for your app data like your cache

Comment: Ok I understand. What about the existing applications?

Comment: I am using Laravel 5.6 . I think it is setting key automatically when we create new project.